# Calculate week of year from date column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

My data frame looks like -

```
id         date
1          2018-08-12
2          2019-01-23
3          2019-04-03
```

I want my data frame looks like -

```
id          date              week
1          2018-08-12           ..
2          2019-01-23           ..
3          2019-04-03           ..
```

I have done so far -

```
df = df.withColumn('week', F.weekofyear('date'))
```

But it treat as 1st Jan is week 1. But I want my starting date should be April (from financial year calendar). How to do this thing in pyspark?

Comment: You'd have to write a function yourself.

Comment: What should be the output corresponding to date : `2019-01-01` ?

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways of doing this. Either you write a `udf` (and lose all benefits of `spark` parallelisation), or you add a value to offset with, such as:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "2018-08-12"),
    (2, "2018-04-01"),
    (3, "2019-04-03"),
],  ["id", "date"])

df = df.withColumn('date', f.to_date(f.col('date')))

df.withColumn('week_of_year_april', 
              f.weekofyear(f.col('date')) - f.weekofyear(f.to_date(f.lit('2018-04-01')))).show()

+---+----------+------------------+
| id|      date|week_of_year_april|
+---+----------+------------------+
|  1|2018-08-12|                19|
|  2|2018-04-01|                 0|
|  3|2019-04-03|                 1|
+---+----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to cater all the dates prior to April for next year. we need to subtract the total weeks of the year in the code.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "2018-08-12"),
    (2, "2018-04-01"),
    (3, "2019-03-03"),
],  ["id", "date"])
df = df.withColumn('date', func.to_date(func.col('date')))

df.withColumn('week_of_year_april',\
              func.when(((func.weekofyear(func.col('date')) - func.weekofyear(func.to_date(func.lit('2018-04-01'))))>func.lit(0)),\
                        (func.weekofyear(func.col('date')) - func.weekofyear(func.to_date(func.lit('2018-04-01')))))\
              .otherwise((func.weekofyear(func.col('date')) - func.weekofyear(func.to_date(func.lit('2018-04-01')))) + func.lit(52)))\
              .show()
+---+----------+------------------+
| id|      date|week_of_year_april|
+---+----------+------------------+
|  1|2018-08-12|                19|
|  2|2018-04-01|                52|
|  3|2019-03-03|                48|
+---+----------+------------------+
```

Comment: `2018-04-01` should be `week 1` isn't?

Comment: Week starts from Monday and ends at Sunday. For year 2018 April 1st was Sunday means last week for previous fiscal year

Comment: Can the method be changed so the week starts on Sunday instead of Monday?

Comment: you can tweak weekofyear function in order to achieve that. make sure it uses spark sql functions to avoid using it as UDF.